# Does a sequence require a unique value for a particular natural number?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In a question, I was asked to prove the existence of a sequence that converges to $\sup S$,  where every element is an element in a set S.

The solution used defined ($A_n$) for $n$ natural numbers as $|\sup S - 1/n| < A_n < \sup S$.

However for any $N$ there are infinite possible elements that satisfy that inequality. Is the a sufficient definition for a sequence?

Comment: Well it is not the definition of a sequence, but an argument proving the existence of a sequence. Spelled out in full, the argument might use the axiom of (countable) choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I said in the comment, you need the axiom of (countable) choice. For every $n\in\Bbb N$ the set $X_n=[\sup S-\frac1n,\sup S]\cap S$ is non-empty. Then by that axiom there is a function $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb R$ with $f(n)\in X_n\subseteq S$, one which gives the sequence $A_n=f(n)$. One easily sees that $\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n=\sup S$.

Answer (score 0):

Take any element $s\in S$ and build a constant sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ on it: $$\forall_{n\in\mathbb N}\ a_n = s$$
The sequence is constant, so it's convergent, hence the existence of a convergent sequence is proven.

Comment: Right. So we may reasonably assume the question was actually a bit harder: to show the existence of a sequence converging to $\sup S$.

Comment: Sorry, I left out a crucial component of the question. It must converge to the SupS.

Comment: Yes, it's required to converge to $\sup S$, but yours in general does not. However, it seems that the question changed after you answered.

Answer (score 0):

No, a sequence has to have unique values. In fact a sequence is just another name for a function from $\mathbb N$.

What you know on the other hand is if you have a sequence of non-empty sets $S_n$ there exists a sequence $s_n\in S_n$, that is you can from your ambiguous definition select a unique definition.

In your concrete example you have only to know that there exists an $A_n$ such that $|\sup S - 1/n| < A_n < \sup S$, and by knowing that you know you can select one $A_n$ that fulfils that requirement.

Better would of course be if you have a concrete method to select $A_n$ (this is often possible, but not in your case since you know nothing more about $S$) because if you haven't you might have to rely on the axiom of choice (which could be considered a little bit controversial).

Comment: The problem is that very possibly $\inf S_n\notin S$, so the sequence $(A_n)_n$ does not satisfy the requirement.

Comment: "but then you have to make sure that $A_n\in S$ is a rather unsatisfying fix. All this near-falsehood just to avoid using countable choice? More precisely, countable Dependent Choice, without which there wouldn't be much modern analysis. It "could be considered a little bit controversial" — by whom, exactly, in 2016? (rhetorical question) That said, it *is* good to be aware of when it's being used.

Comment: Since that was not a generically viable fix so I removed that part. However in practical situations there would often exists some way to circumvent AC (even though the method may differ from case to case).

Comment: Point is, if $S$ were given constructively, then it might be possible to supply a constructiion of $A_n\in S$ for each $n$. But it isn't: $S$ is an arbitrary bounded set of reals, arbitrary in the sense of classical mathematics, which accepts AC. The desired result is a pure existence theorem, so there's no shame in using a nonconstructive principle to prove it.

Comment: @BrianO Point is, if it's possible to supply a construction of $A_n\in S$ it would have it's advantage to know that you can get by without using AC.

Comment: In common usage "constructions" (as in "constructive analysis", "constructive set theory", intuitionism) don't employ AC, so of course.

Answer (score 0):

This is a stronger result: it says that *all* sequences that fulfill the condition do converge to $\sup S$.

The proof is non-constructive (it doesn't give a sequence explicitly).

Comment: That definition with only work for certain sets, as not all sets will include An. What allows us to guarantee that there always exists an explicit sequence?

Comment: @Hamza: right. The answer will depend on how $S$ is defined.

Comment: It still remains to show that there exists at least one such sequence. Absent that, it isn't a stronger result, as it might be vacuously true.